# How to have a 100% width background inside container of twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently building a wordpress site, where I need a 100% width background (css color, no image) for a div. My div is inside a container and I can't modify the html. So, I was wondering if there was any way with css to do this. I have already tried the padding+margin hack, but it didn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="main span12">
       <div class="row-fluid blue"> <!--this is the div that needs the background-->
          <div class="span4">some content</div>
           <div class="span4">some content</div>
          <div class="span4">some content</div>
          </div>
       <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span12"> some other content, doesn't need the background</div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated. I tried this one : http://www.sitepoint.com/css-extend-full-width-bars/ but it didn't work.

Comment: Pseudo elements to the rescue - ** http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/ **

Answer (score 1):

Based on this article from CSS Tricks ([**Full Width Browser Bars**](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/) ).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="level"></div>
  <div class="level purple"></div>
  <div class="level"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container {
  width:960px;
  margin: 0  auto;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.level {
  height:100px;
  background: #bada55;
}

.purple {
  position: relative;
  background: #663399;
}

.purple:before, 
.purple:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #663399;  /* Match the background */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 9999px;   /* some huge width */
} 
.purple:before {
  right: 100%; 
}
.purple:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

**[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JtcfB)**

Support should be IE8 & up

Comment: why doesn't it work if I don't set `min-height` or `height`? setting height doesn't really work for me! :(

Comment: I only added the height to demo it. If **your** div has __content__ it will automatically have height.

Comment: erm...my div has content, but it still isn't working! just the min-height part is colored!

Comment: Then provide us with your own demo so we can debug it. - see : http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pielA

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/vmZh5eOlxa it is in bootply. somewhere it is crashing with boostrap, because firebug shows me that the containing row doesn't have any height. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: apparently it's the absolute position that is preventing the row to get the height of it's children. :/

Comment: Nope...the only things that are absolutely positioned are the pseudo-elements and they have nothing to do with the content or height. They only get their height from the height of the actual element.

Comment: yup, I know that. but deleting the position attribute shows me the bgcolor in firebug! what am I missing?

Comment: Thus technique causes problems in Chrome. try click-dragging to the right - the whole page scrolls to reveal the extra space.

Comment: Not in my demo it doesn't.